# How to host a download file on a website for an application

Tags: wordpress, file, web-applications, download, web-hosting

I believe wordpress has download limits (it'd probably crash your site if someone spammed download).  A website like: [multiloginapp](https://multiloginapp.com/get-software/) provides you with the download, where as a website like [winautomation](http://www.winautomation.com/download/) provides you the download link through an e-mail.

How do I go about implementing something like that for an application I have created?  The only solution that I know of would be to use an external provider and link that with a password

Or to perhaps do what Winautomation do and when you sign up to download the application, it send you an email where you click the link and it pings it to you

Any ideas as I'm keen to get my application out there.

*UPDATED*

So broken down:

1) Provide the link to download. [WordPress Download Manager]

2) *OPTIONAL* Use Pretty Links Wordpress.  This ensures that you can make the link specific to your site

3) Use a hosting provider like sabercat.  Honestly this is the issue here.  I want to have a host provider ping me it.  I can't use my own host yet but I feel like this is the last issue to address.  Two problems with this: Security is lacking unless you can encrypt or provide a password.  The other is credibility.  Would you buy from a legitimate business that users SABERCAT to give you their application?  Maybe.. but you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

For hosting a file in WordPress site first of all you might need unlimited bandthwidth or a dedicated server so instead it's wise to use a free file hosting services